# ¿Como puedo crear un array nuevo a partir de otro filtrando por una propiedad?

Tags: javascript, array

Alguien sabe como puedo modificar la estructura de mis datos para tener un array que contenga las clases diferentes y dentro de las clases sus parámetros?

Me explico mas en detalle con este ejemplo:

```
Array(100)
47: ["4.6,3.2,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa"]
48: ["5.3,3.7,1.5,0.2,Iris-setosa"]
49: ["5.0,3.3,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa"]
50: ["7.0,3.2,4.7,1.4,Iris-versicolor"]
51: ["6.4,3.2,4.5,1.5,Iris-versicolor"]
52: ["6.9,3.1,4.9,1.5,Iris-versicolor"]
53: ["5.5,2.3,4.0,1.3,Iris-versicolor"]
54: ["6.5,2.8,4.6,1.5,Iris-versicolor"]
55: ["5.7,2.8,4.5,1.3,Iris-versicolor"]
```

Vale tengo este array que contiene estos datos y me gustaría ponerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
array:0 "Iris-setosa"
              0:{4.6,3.2,1.4,0.2}
              1:{5.3,3.7,1.5,0.2}
              2:{5.0,3.3,1.4,0.2}
array:1 "Iris-versicolor"
              0:{4.6,3.2,1.4,0.2}
              1:{5.3,3.7,1.5,0.2}
              2:{5.0,3.3,1.4,0.2}
              0:{4.6,3.2,1.4,0.2}
              1:{5.3,3.7,1.5,0.2}
              2:{5.0,3.3,1.4,0.2}
```

Es decir crear un nuevo array con los atributos y dentro de estos con sus valores

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Qué problema tienes? Por favor leer [ask] y [mcve]. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta solución me parece aducada, el primer ciclo for es para crear tu JSON con todos los titles ("Iris-setosa","Iris-versicolor", "Iris..."...), el segundo es para llenar tu estructura JSON.

La razón de hacerlo en dos ciclos es porque es más optimizado que crear la propiedad title si es que no existe con if, puesto que si es un dataset muy grande se harían muchas comparaciones que empeorarían el comportamiento del algoritmo

```javascript
   let original = [
        ["4.6,3.2,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa"],
        ["5.3,3.7,1.5,0.2,Iris-setosa"],
        ["7.0,3.2,4.7,1.4,Iris-versicolor"]
    ];
    let response = {};
    for (let str of original) {
        let title = str[0].split(',');
        response[title[title.length - 1]] = {
            values: []
        }
    }
    for (let str of original) {
        let temp = [];
        let numbers = str[0].split(',');
        for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length - 1; ++i) {
            temp.push( parseFloat(numbers[i]) );
        }
        response[numbers[numbers.length - 1]].values.push(temp)
    }
```